# How to change the known ciphertext so the known plaintext is changed in AES CBC mode?

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc

I already read a blog about the padding oracle and also some posts about how to change the plaintext but it didn't work out.

So I have the encrypted cookie (AES_CBC):

```
5468697320697320616e204956343536 d6ca0a2883280762915414c54e97df1b 40871b72f45ec7f9510a080095436d51 4129e137aaac86a0f7fa8bd3d250b9d1 df35b668fcb93f00bb06692560a3fed8 a3b523d385f1477b6daac14ff2416c67
```

which I could decrypt with the padding oracle to:

```
hex: 5468697320697320616e204956343536 7b22757365726e616d65223a20226775 657374222c202265787069726573223a 2022323030302d30312d3037222c2022 69735f61646d696e223a202266616c73 65227d0d0d0d0d0d0d0d0d0d0d0d0d0d
ASCII: This is an IV456{"username": "guest", "expires": "2000-01-07", "is_admin": "false"}
```

I now have to change the cookie date so it is not expired and I also have to change `is_admin` to `true`. So first I wanted to change the year in the date to `3000` to only have to change one number.

The expiry year is part of the 4th plaintext block, byte 3: `P_43`
The corresponding encrypted ciphertext block byte will be defined as: `C_43`
The manipulated plaintext byte will be defined as: `P_43'`
The corresponding ciphertext byte will be defined as: `C_43'`
The bytes from other blocks will have the same definition `[cipher=C or plain=P]_[block][byte]`

Since I want to change the number `2`, I know that `P_43=32` (ascii to hex).
 
In addition I know that I want to change the plaintext to show the number 3 so `P_43'=33`
 
Looking at the ciphertext I can also see that `C_43=e1` and `C_33=1b`

So what I already tried, is the following:
Calculate `C_33' = (P_43') xor (P_43) xor (C_33) = 33 xor 32 xor 1b = 1a` and change `C_33` to `C_33' = 1a`

Since it did not work I also tried some other stuff (which made no sense for me) I read in the forums like:
`C_43' = (P_43') xor (P_43) xor (C_43) = 33 xor 32 xor e1 = e0` or
`C_33' = (P_43') xor (C_33)`

Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong? I wrote my own padding oracle script based on the blog post about it and I successfully decrypted the message but I really don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: As the entire block of which you do the XOR changes if you try and change the ciphertext, I don't see how you could be doing this. Are you sure this is a question that was asked of you?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Are you sure that this is the reason why it not works? Looking at the equations ```C_N=E(P_N xor C_N-1)``` and ```P_N'=D(C_N) xor C_N-1'``` and inserting the first one in the second on leads to ```P_N'=D(E(P_N xor C_N-1)) xor C_N-1'  =  P_N'=P_N xor C_N-1 xor C_N-1'```. And then I only transformed the equation so that I have C_N-1'. Am I missing something here?